# Is there any difference in mapping commands with <Cmd> or with :?

Tags: key-bindings, command

As per title, is there any difference in mapping commands when using `<Cmd>` or `:` ?
For example, is there any difference between the two following mappings?

```
nnoremap <leader>c :close<cr>
nnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>close<cr>
```

If there is no difference, which one is encouraged to be used?

Comment: What parts of `:help <Cmd>` are you struggling with?

Comment: `The special text <Cmd> begins a "command mapping", it executes the command
directly without changing modes.` and just after `noremap x <Cmd>echo mode(1)<CR>`. What is the point of adding `nnoremap` if the command is executed without changing mode?

Comment: `nnoremap` and "changing modes" are two totally unrelated concepts so one can't preclude the other. Also, the example you quoted uses `noremap`, not `nnoremap`, so your logic is hard to follow.

Comment: Ops, I read a ‘n’ more. Now the doc is more clear but still I don’t see the answer of my question in :h <Cmd>.

Comment: The "I quote `noremap` and then I talk about `nnoremap`" part was the hardest to follow but the rest is still just baseless assumptions and speculations. `noremap` and "changing modes" are unrelated so using `<Cmd>` and using `noremap` can't be mutually exclusive.

Comment: … so the answer to my initial question (if you have) is…? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through the basics first…

A mapping is a way of telling Vim "when I press *these* keys, I want you to pretend that I pressed *those* keys instead".

In the example below, I press `a` but Vim acts as if I pressed `b` and I get the effect of pressing `b` instead of the effect of pressing `a`:

```
map a b
```

By default, mappings are "recursive", which means that, if a mapped key is encountered in the right-hand side, you will get the mapped behavior instead of the original behavior of a key. In the example above, the expected behavior of pressing `a` is the cursor moving to the beginning of the current word or that of the previous word, which is what `:help b` does. But, if `b` happens to also be mapped to something else, say…

```
map b gUiw
```

then pressing `a` will make the current word uppercase instead of moving the cursor as expected. I can avoid it by telling Vim that my mapping is "non-recursive", which is done by prepending `nore` to `map`:

```
noremap a b
```

Which one to use, recursive or non-recursive, depends on whether you want to use mapped keys in your RHS or not.

Now, it rarely makes sense to design mappings for all modes and, if you really want it, it is not super practical anyway. That's why you see things like `inoremap` or `nmap`: the specific mode in which the mapping should be defined is prepended to the `map` or `noremap`.

`:[nore]map`, which I used in my example, is a bit of an outlier in `:help map-modes` because it covers *four* modes: normal, visual, select, and operator-pending. This is specifically intended for creating new motions, because motions are used in all four modes. My goal in creating that mapping was to have a new motion so `:[nore]map` is well suited. With a single mapping, I can press `a` in all four modes and expect the same outcome.

When you decide to make your mapping an insert mode mapping, say, all `:i[nore]map` does is define your mapping for insert mode. It won't be accessible from other modes, which is as neat as it gets, but it doesn't mean that you can't switch modes in the RHS. In your example:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :close<cr>
```

you are defining a normal mode mapping that switches to command-line mode. In theory, this is absolutely fine but not so in practice. One potential issue is that `:help :` automatically adds a range if it was preceded by a number. If, somehow, you pressed `9` before pressing `<leader>c`, the command that is actually executed is not `:close`, it is:

```
:.,.+8close
```

which may or may not be what you want. And there are other issues in other use cases that I won't discuss here. Suffice to say that, for literally decades, the best practice has been to add `:help c_ctrl-u` between `:` and the command name, in order to clear the command-line and thus remove any automatic range:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :<C-u>close<cr>
```

`:help <Cmd>` also mentions the `<C-o>:` hack which, like the one above, certainly gets the job done. But those hacks do nothing to solve the underlying problem, which is that you leave normal mode for an interactive mode you don't care about, all because you want its outcome and so on.

`:help <Cmd>` solves that problem rather elegantly, by preventing mode switching. Because there is no `:` anymore, you don't get the automatic range and you don't have to add `<C-u>` to remove it, which makes your mapping cleaner and less brittle:

```
nnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>close<cr>
```

To circle back to your question, the choice is not between:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :close<cr>
```

and:

```
nnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>close<cr>
```

But between:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :<C-u>close<cr>
```

and:

```
nnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>close<cr>
```

To help you choose,

- `nnoremap <leader>c :close<cr>` is naïve and brittle, avoid it.
- `nnoremap <leader>c :<C-u>close<cr>` is a lot less fragile but slightly "dirty", it also works in older Vim versions.
- `nnoremap <leader>c <Cmd>close<cr>` is functionally perfect but it won't work in older Vim versions.

FWIW, I tend to use `<Cmd>` in new mappings when necessary but I didn't bother going through all the `:<C-u>` mappings in my config because, well… they still work.

Also FWIW, I know that it was just a quick example, but the following would make more sense, and without any mode switching issue and related hacks:

```
nnoremap <leader>c <C-w>c
```

Just sayin'.